# Search in zathura bookmarks

Tags: pdf, search, zathura, bookmarks

Is it possible to search in bookmarks and "subookmarks" created from table of contents?
I need to read 1200 pages MCU datasheet and fast orientation in bookmarks is necessary. This feature is for me unfortunately dealbreaker.

Is there am way how I could implement this feature?

Thanks for help